# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagekitio'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import the `imagekitio` module for a project I am working on. However, I am getting the follwing error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagekitio'
```

At first, you might think that the module is not installed, but I checked and it is actually installed. For instance:

```
pip show imagekitio
```

An the response is:

```
Name: imagekitio
Version: 3.1.0
Summary: Python wrapper for the ImageKit API
Home-page: https://github.com/imagekit-developer/imagekit-python
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: 
Location: C:\Users\nekov\Cloud-Drive\Máster Data Engineering\Módulo 2 - Arquitecturas transaccionales\M02-proyecto-consolidacion\Solucion proyecto consolidacion\project_env\Lib\site-packages
Requires: requests, requests-toolbelt, urllib3
Required-by:
```

I am executing this in a new environment I have created. I have tried deactivating/activating the environment again, uninstalling the `imagekitio` and installing again, but it does not work.

Do you know how I could solve this issue?

Comment: What is your Python version? If it is earlier than 3.6 the module is not supported.

Comment: What kind of "new environment" is this? conda, venv, virtualenv? How are you executing the script throwing the error? How do you know the environment in which you're executing the script has activated the environment containing the library?

Comment: Python version is  3.11.3. The environment is a `venv`. I am executing the script in a Jupyter Notebook and I understand that the library is active because when I run `pip show imagekitio` it tells me that the package exist and is installed. Actually I manage to uninstall it previously

Comment: You're running `pip show...` from *within* the Jupyter notebook or from a separate terminal window?

Comment: You probably haven't installed Jupyter notebook in your venv, but have it installed globally. So when you start it up, you're using the global version, which doesn't know about your venv's packages.

Comment: within the Jupyter notebook. Obviously it would be `!pip show imagekitio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments provided by other users, I managed to identify the problem. Effectively, the package was installed, but what was not installed in the new environment was jupyter and jupyter lab. I installed it, and again it showed the same error. I close the environment created and all jupyter instances and reopened all again. Then it worked.

I post this solution in case someone has the same problem in the future, as the solution was suggested by comments and not replying directly to the question.